# IE7 Compatibility Tag

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I have an ASP.Net web application using Framework 3.5, an IE9.0 browser, and I'm using IE7 standard by including the following tag in the master page:

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"
```

My web application is working fine with Firefox and Chrome but I have some performance issues with IE.  Will this tag affect performance??

If yes can you provide references to the articles or documentation showing this?

Thanks

Comment: Firefox & Chrome will ignore the tag and render your site using modern standards. If it works fine in Firefox & Chrome then why target IE7 at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand.  If your site works fine in FF and Chrome, then it's standards compliant.  You should be using IE in full standards mode, not trying to be compatible with IE7 rendering.

You should use IE=Edge, this will ensure your site is always rendered in the most standard mode the browser offers.  This is what you'll get in FF and Chrome.

As for performance, it's hard to say how emulating other versions can affect performance, but it probably shouldn't, but then that all depends on what elements your performance issues are related to.  For instance, using an older version may involve using an older version of the javascript engine which may not be as well optimized.